# Error Setting Up Frontend Login in django marcador tutorial

Tags: python, django

I am a newbie using django 1.11.5 installed.This a tutorial from [macador app project](http://django-marcador.keimlink.de/en/frontend_login.html).I have already created the view in thhe project main template.my login and logout is not working.When i run the runserver command,I get the following error.

## terminal

Performing system checks...

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x7f087adf5aa0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/Desktop/bookmarksmanager/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 228, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/Desktop/bookmarksmanager/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 125, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/root/Desktop/bookmarksmanager/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 359, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/root/Desktop/bookmarksmanager/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 346, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/root/Desktop/bookmarksmanager/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/root/Desktop/bookmarksmanager/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 16, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/root/Desktop/bookmarksmanager/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 26, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/root/Desktop/bookmarksmanager/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 254, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/root/Desktop/bookmarksmanager/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/root/Desktop/bookmarksmanager/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 405, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/root/Desktop/bookmarksmanager/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/root/Desktop/bookmarksmanager/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 398, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/root/Desktop/bookmarksmanager/myenv/src/mysite/urls.py", line 27, in <module>
    name='mysite_login'),
  File "/root/Desktop/bookmarksmanager/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py", line 85, in url
    raise TypeError('view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().')
TypeError: view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().
```

from templates:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block title %}Login{% endblock %}
{% block toggle_login %}{% endblock %}
{% block heading %}
<h2>Login</h2>
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<form action="{% url "mysite_login" %}" method="post" accept-             charset="utf-8">

{{ form|crispy }}
{% csrf_token %}
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}">
<input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

mysite.urls:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'^bookmarksapp/',include('bookmarksapp.urls')),
url(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'template_name': 'login.html'},
 name='mysite_login'),
url(r'^logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout',
{'next_page': reverse_lazy('bookmarksapp_bookmark_list')},    name='mysite_logout'),
```

]

settings.py

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

LOGIN_URL = 'mysite_login'
LOGOUT_URL = 'mysite_logout'
```

Comment: Post your `bookmarksapp.urls` as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your `mysites.urls` as following.

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
from django.contrib.auth.views import login, logout

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'^bookmarksapp/',include('bookmarksapp.urls')),
url(r'^login/$', login, {'template_name': 'login.html'},
 name='mysite_login'),
url(r'^logout/$', logout,
{'next_page': reverse_lazy('bookmarksapp_bookmark_list')},    name='mysite_logout'),
```

As error said your views must be callable.

Comment: Hi Darshit thanks for the response.I get the concept when i am mapping the urls from view.py ,it is just a bit confusing when I am mapping the url from the template.to be precise url(r'^login/$', login, {'template_name': 'login.html'},
 name='mysite_login').#my first project in django

Answer (score 0):

I think there's some error in bookmarksapp.urls file. Can you post its content ?
Also, modify your settings.py -

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]

LOGIN_URL = 'mysite_login'
LOGOUT_URL = 'mysite_logout'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'bookmarksapp_bookmark_list'
```